# trying to get values from a HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML form where i dynamically create elements and set its name , value attributes .

when i tried to access the value say document .formname.nameoftheelement.value then i get the error that value is undefined.

Then i tried to use the following function to access the values .it returns the input elements as 4 but value as null when i it already has predefined value .

```
function returnTheStoredValues(getTableName) {
    //Array arrList = new Array(20);
    var tableName = document.getElementById (getTableName);
    console.log("The table name" + tableName);
      if (tableName) {
          var inputs = tableName.getElementsByTagName ('td');
          console.log("the inputs are " + inputs.length);
          if (inputs) {
              console.log("inputs not equal to null")
              for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {

                    console.log("the value in phones table are " + inputs[i].value);
                    //arrList[i] = inputs[i].value;

              }
          }
      }
      //return arrList;
}
```

The html code is

Phone

```
         <table id="email_table">
         <tr>
         <td><h3>Email</h3></td>
         <td><input value="+" type="submit" onClick="checkTheEmailButtonClicked()"></td>
         </tr>
         </table>
        <table>
             <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td><input type="submit" value ="Save" onclick="getData();"/></td>
                     <td><input type="submit" value = "Cancel"/></td>
                  </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Appreciate all your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the values of the *input* elements, so:

```
function returnTheStoredValues(getTableName) {
    var arrList = [];
    var table = document.getElementById(getTableName);
    var inputs = table.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      arrList[i] = inputs[i].value;
    }
    return arrList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're getting the TD's and not the INPUT's?

```
var inputs = tableName.getElementsByTagName('td');
```

Should be

```
var inputs = tableName.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

By the way, if you use a Javascript framework, your code will be happier.

Comment: How will a framework fix an error like using the wrong *tagName*?

Comment: @RobG - It won't.  jQuery isn't THAT magical =)  But in the long run, wouldn't you say it's worth it to learn?

Comment: @anon - it depends. If I was a newbie that needed to get something working in a real hurry and had no idea what I was doing, using a framework likely makes sense. But if efficient, cross-browser code is important in a non-trivial program, frameworks are generally unsuitable. And using one means you likely won't learn how either.

Comment: @anon - PS. It can be seen from my answer that the code that does the work is no more than the offered jQuery solution, setting up the variables takes a couple of lines. I know which one will run faster and in pretty much any browser since IE 5 (and adding support for it would be very easy, but I suspect there aren't too many people still using it on the web). jQuery can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to look into using jQuery for accessing elements through JavaScript.

You could then re-write your function to the following:

```
function returnTheStoredValues(getTableName) {
    return $("#email_table input").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
}
```